# Delete method at end of class in java

Tags: java, selenium

My test:-
    public class Sample{

```
@Test
public void method1()
{
  // creation of user
}

@Test
public void method2()
{
  // verify the user
}

}
```

At the end of the class. i want to delete a user object. How do i delete it ?

Scenario1:-

If i use deletion of user in teardown method, it will make call at the end of method1 and method2. So this won't work for me.

Scenario2:-

If i use deletion of user in method2(finally block), it will work.

Is there any way to do deletion of user separately at the end of class.

Comment: Could this be what you are looking for? http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/AfterClass.html

Comment: What's the problem in making a third test method testing the deletion of a user?

Comment: @JasonSperske Ya. Thats what am looking for. Thanks . its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is scenario 3 :)

Instead of using the `@After` annotation on your tear down method use the annotation [`@AfterClass`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/AfterClass.html). It will cause this method to execute after all tests in that class are run.